# Calculate median value for a column and say if this value is "OK" or "ERROR" if falls within acceptable range

Tags: awk, sort

I would like to calculate the median value of a particular column in a .txt file, output that value and also say if that output value is ok. I can do the initial steps and output the median value, however it cannot say if the output value is within the acceptable range.

I get a syntax error message with the following code:

```
sort -nk9 filename | awk '{a[i++]=$9;} END {x=int((i+1)/2); y=((a[x-1] + a[x])/2); z=(a[x-1]);
if ((y >= 0.5 && y <= 2) || (z >= 0.5 && z <=2));
   {if (x < (i+1)/2) 
   print "Median OR =", y "ALL OK"; 
   else print "Median OR =", z "ALL OK"}; 
else print "ERROR - OR outside range 0.5 - 2.0"}'
```

Comment: for one column you can use: `cat column.txt | awk '{ sum+=$2 } END {if (sum/NR>=0.5 && 2>=sum/NR) print "Median Above Threshold, and its value is " sum/NR}'` In this case it'll add all of the 2nd column values, create a median, and compare it to the range you provided.

Comment: Thank you Simply_Me for your suggestion. It works however, the code outputs the MEAN value and not the MEDIAN (middle value in the list) which is what I need.

Comment: @bob what are the comparisons supposed to be comparing ?One of them seems to be making sure the second to last array item is between two values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
awk '{sum+=$9;a[x++]=$9;b[$9]++}b[$9]>Mode{Mode=$9}END{print "Mean: " sum/x "\nMedian: "a[int((x-1)/2)]"\nMode: " Mode}' file
```

Layed out neater

```
awk '
{
     sum+=$9
     a[x++]=$9
     b[$9]++
}
b[$9]>Mode{Mode=$9}
END{
    print "Mean: " sum/x 
    print "Median: "a[int((x-1)/2)] 
    print "Mode: " Mode
}' file
```

Also i will add some logic for the comparisons but i don't actually know what you are trying to compare as your variable are just called x,y,z and do may or may not have the correct equations

Answer (score 2):

I am grateful for the code `user78605` has provided, since it guided me in the direction of how to find the median in my queries. The above-mentioned code, however, overlooks certain conditions which are required to calculate the median correctly.

## Issues:

1. Blank trailing lines (if they exist in the file), should not be counted since counting them affects the data size and hence the average, median, mode, as well as other statistical quantities. Same should most likely be done for the rows which do not have numerical values (id est: `"abc"`, `"28b"`, `"h2f"`, `""`, and et cetera).
2. Median is the middle value of not the original data set, but an ordered data set. That is, the data for which the median is to be found must be sorted first.
3. If the quantity of values in an ordered data set is even, the average of the two middle values must be taken.
4. Mode is a value which has the highest frequency. It is possible for the data set to have more than one mode, in which case two or more values need to be listed as mode.

The following is my expansion of the code, taking the above-mentioned conditions into account:

```
awk -F',' '
{col=$1}{if((col ~  /^-?[0-9]*([.][0-9]+)?$/) && ($0!=""))                 
{
     sum+=col;
     a[x++]=col;
     b[col]++
     if(b[col]>hf){hf=b[col]}
}
}
END{n = asort(a);idx=int((x+1)/2)
     print "Mean: " sum/x
     print "Median: " ((idx==(x+1)/2) ? a[idx] : (a[idx]+a[idx+1])/2)
     for (i in b){if(b[i]==hf){(k=="") ? (k=i):(k=k FS i)}{FS=","}}
     print "Mode: " k
}' file
```

## EXPLANATION:

Solution for issue #1:

> `col=$1` #easier to change columns if stored in a variable.
>   `(col ~  /^-?[0-9]*([.][0-9]+)?$/)` #The string must only comprise numerals, a period    (decimal separator), or a dash (minus sign). [Only the scientific notation is overlooked.]
>   `($0!="")` #the entire row must not be blank.

On the eligible rows, perform the following loop operations:

> `sum+=col` #(Short for `sum=sum+col`.) Sum of all values.
>   `a[x++]=col` #Every value is stored into an array.
>   `b[col]++` #Values in `col` are treated as surrogate keys of array `b`. Hence there are only as many elements in `b` as the number of unique values in `col`. This iterator creates an array of frequency counts. (Short for `b[col]=b[col]+1`.)
>   `if(b[col]>hf){hf=b[col]}` #Let `hf` stand for "the highest frequency". Loop through all the frequencies and update `hf` only if higher frequencies are found. `hf` is initially "" (nothing).

Solution for issue #2:
After the looping operations are completed:

> Sort the values stored in the array: `n = asort(a)`
>
> It is important to note that the original indices of array `a` ranged from "0" to "x-1". In addition to sorting, the new index range is from "1" to "x". This is why I use `int((x+1)/2)` instead of 
>  `int((x-1)/2)` as the index which holds the median - or the smaller of the two numbers which will be averaged out to a median.

Solution for issue #3:

> `((idx == (x+1)/2) ? a[idx] : (a[idx]+a[idx+1])/2)`
>   This is a shorthand notation for an if-else construction:
>   If `int((x+1)/2)` equals `(x+1)/2` then the number of values is odd, and the median will be `a[idx]`. If this is not so, `int()` will round down `(x+1)/2` to the nearest integer signifying that the number of values is even. In this case, the average of `a[idx]` and `a[idx]+1` will be the median.

Solution for issue #4:

> `for (i in b) {if(b[i]==hf){(k=="") ? (k=i):(k=k FS i)}{FS=","}}`
>   Since `hf` is the value which represents the highest frequency in the data set, if any value of b is equal to `hf`, its surrogate key is the mode, or at least one of the modes.
>   This code concatenates all surrogate keys, `i`, which match the criterion and stores them into a variable, `k`, that can be printed on one row with the title "Mode".

## Further Adjustments:

`-F` should be adjusted according to whichever character is being used as a column separator in the file.

If the file has headers on the first line, add `NR > 1` in front of `{col=$1}`.

`FS` was used to concatenate two variables together. The use of `FS` is especially useful when one chooses not to use the separator. That is, `FS=""`.

## Data

The following data was used for experimentation in order to create the script:

```
10
20
10
20.5
50
30
40
50
10
30
20.5


-h
h

4.35
-537
0
-0

30
d




.
```

## RESULTS:

```
Mean: -13.2281
Median: 20.25
Mode: 10,30
```